# REST response object with Java Optional getters

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, option-type

I am writing a REST Service in Spring Boot. I want to make some of the fields of my DTO classes to be accessed as Optional getters. Here is the example.

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY, property = "profileType", visible = true, defaultImpl = InvalidUserDTO.class)
@JsonSubTypes({ @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ClientDTO.class, name = "CLIENT"), @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = DriverDTO.class, name = "DRIVER") })
public abstract class UserDTO {

    private String password;

    private Optional<String> email;
```

With such approach, in my REST response I am getting something like `email: {"present" : true}` instead of the real value of the email.

To resolve this, I tried adding the Jdk8Module dependency to the classpath.

However, that only caused the following error while trying to call my service on the endpoints that use Optionals:

```
    {"message":"Internal Server Error","details":"Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: 

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.ReferenceTypeSerializer.withResolved(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/BeanProperty;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/jsontype/TypeSerializer;
Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonSerializer;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/util/NameTransformer;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude$Include;)
Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/std/ReferenceTypeSerializer;"}
```

Is there something I am missing? Why does that happen?

Here is the ObjectMapper config:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MainApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Autowired
    void configureObjectMapper(final ObjectMapper mapper) {
        mapper
            .registerModule(new ParameterNamesModule())
            .registerModule(new Jdk8Module());
    }    

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        servletContext.setInitParameter("webAppRootKey", "newfacesBackend.root");
        servletContext.setInitParameter("isLog4jAutoInitializationDisabled", "true");
        super.onStartup(servletContext);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(MainApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Gradle dependencies:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.4.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.github.ben-manes.versions'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'


configurations {
    compile.exclude group:'ch.qos.logback'
}

dependencies {


    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:2.9.4")

    compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:2.9.4")
```

Comment: Are all your Jackson dependencies in the same 2.9.1 version?

Comment: Did you add `Jdk8Module` on your [ObjectMapper](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-optional)?

Comment: @KarolDowbecki I don't know, they come from Spring Boot Starter 1.5.4. I don't declare them explicitly

Comment: @Dherik Yes, but that changes nothing.

Comment: How are you doing this (adding the Jdk8Module)? Post the code on the question

Comment: @Dherik Updated.

Comment: I added an answer. If not work, I will delete.

Answer (score 1):

You should register your JDK8 module with the mapper like:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module());
```

OR,

You can do this globally by adding the following to your main Spring Boot Application Class:

```
  @Autowired
  void configureObjectMapper(final ObjectMapper mapper) {
   mapper.registerModule(new ParameterNamesModule())
  .registerModule(new Jdk8Module());
  }
```

The dependency for `ParameterNamesModule` is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-module-parameter-names</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I can't find this ParameterNamesModule? What's the dependency for it?

Comment: Edited answer with the dependency

Comment: Without this dependency it's just all the same error. Adding it causes this: "Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.fasterxml.jackson.module.paramnames.ParameterNamesModule]: Factory method 'parameterNamesModule' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.module.paramnames.ParameterNamesModule"

Comment: Please have a look [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8). Adding those dependencies and registering all the modules should ideally help you, don't really know why you're getting these errors.

Answer (score 1):

Had this problem, turned out I had incompatible dependencies

You have dependency `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:1.5.4.RELEASE`:

```
buildscript {
  dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.4.RELEASE")
  }
}
...
dependencies {
  compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
}
```

which has its own dependency `com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.8`
and is not compatible by another fasterxml dependency provided by you:

```
compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:2.9.4")
```

**Solution**

Just downgrade jackson-datatype-jdk8 version:

```
compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:2.8.8")
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete the `configureObjectMapper` and try this:

```
@Configuration
public class ObjectMapperConfig

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = builder.build();
        objectMapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module());
        return objectMapper;
    }

}
```